Adding ssl(tls) certificate to docker for accessing docker repository
Get “https://registry-1.docker.io/v2”: proxyconnect tcp: tls: failed to verify certification: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
This is the error i am facing while trying to run docker for a selfhosted agent
I have tried to add certificates in many paths but I am still facing the same error.I want to know where exactly the certificate should be placed
My organization is behind a proxy, the proxy is added to the azure windows VM.The VM itself is able to use the internet which tells that the proxy setup is correct and the VM has proper certificate
How to make the docker use the certificate present in the VM MMC.
We have tried to export and use the certificate in - azure.ACRregistry.io:5000 folder.
However the error is coming since docker is not able to connect to the registry-1.docker.io

What's your agent OS? and which task does the error report? If you logon to the agent machine directly, run docker and try to pull image, does it succeed? Please refer to the link to add the cert, restart the docker service then have a check, let me know if it works, thanks.
